# Cross browser Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, cross-browser

I am using the following code to convert a dynamic string into a valid class.

```
domain.replace('.','_','gi')
```

This works fine in all major browsers, but not in Internet Explorer and I'm wondering why. The gi flags are for global and case insensitive, but removing them means that the replace doesn't work in Firefox either.

Any ideas on how I change this to make it more friendly with more browers?

Comment: What happens or doesn't happen? What is the expected and actual result?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to use an actual regexp instead of a string:

```
domain.replace(/\./g, "_")
```

The third argument (flags) is non-standard.

Comment: @elusive: Why would you need the `i` flag for a dot?

Comment: Good point. I recognized it a few seconds after i submitted. Sorry about that. +1 for the non-standard hint ;)

Comment: Cracking! That's what I was missing. Will accept in 6 minutes :)

Answer (score 7):

You need to do it like this:

```
domain.replace(/\./g, '_');
```